# ffmpeg not converting entire file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert a .tak file to .flac, but ffmpeg stops converting before the end (with no error message).

```
>ffmpeg -i CDImage.tak CDImage.flac
ffmpeg version N-69659-gc0367f7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-
libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enab
le-zlib
  libavutil      54. 18.100 / 54. 18.100
  libavcodec     56. 21.102 / 56. 21.102
  libavformat    56. 19.100 / 56. 19.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5.  9.104 /  5.  9.104
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, tak, from 'CDImage.tak':
  Duration: 00:17:35.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1013 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: tak, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16p
Output #0, flac, to 'CDImage.flac':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.19.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.21.102 flac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (tak (native) -> flac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=   83540kB time=00:10:54.19 bitrate=1046.1kbits/s
video:0kB audio:83532kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
 overhead: 0.009689%
```

As you can see, the input file is 17:35.95, but ffmpeg is only converting 10:54.19 of it. Does anyone know what's going on here?

edit: I tried it with a different tak file and got the same result. Only 27 minutes of a 50 minute tak was converted to flac. I get the exact same output file times when converting to wav, so I'm guessing it must either be something with the tak files I have, or with ffmpeg's tak decoder.

Comment: `--enable-decoder=tak`

Comment: According to 'ffmpeg -decoders', tak is already enabled.

Comment: Please provide a sample file if possible so I can attempt to duplicate this issue. How was the file created? Do other decoders report the same duration?

Comment: It's actually working now. I have no idea what happened. I restarted my computer, but that's all. There's no reason my computer would have to restart for ffmpeg to work, right?